# Android and CherryPy

Tags: java, android, python, cherrypy

I am developing an Android application in which I have to make a POST HTTP request on a REST API built with cherrypy.

Here is the java code of the app:

```
public String post(String host,int port,String path,String msg) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL ("http",host,port,path);
    Log.e("track","sto per connettermi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    Log.e("track","connesso");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(msg.getBytes());
    conn.getOutputStream().close();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()
            )
    );
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line);
    in.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is the python code for the REST API:

```
def POST(self,*uri,**params):
    if uri[0] == 'userAuth':
        tempJson = json.loads(cherrypy.request.body.read())
        user_name = tempJson['user_name']
        pwd = tempJson['pwd']
        if user_name in self.users:
            return json.dumps({"user_id":str(self.users.index(user_name)),"result":True})
        return json.dumps({"result":"Wrong Credentials","success":False})
```

On the cherrypy server I am receiving the following error: 
`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`
The problem is that I send the data through the java stream and I am not able to decode it in python.
Is there a way to send the data directly as a String or a way to decode it in python?

**SOLVED**
Fixed adding the line:
`conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");`

Comment: replace msg String with this {"user_name":"name} see if it works.

Comment: If you are going to do this a lot I suggest you use Retrofit with okHttp. It will simplify JSON creation.

Answer (score 1):

Define your `POST` method as:

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def POST(self,*uri,**params):
    req = cherrypy.request
    if uri[0] == 'userAuth':
        user_name = req.json['user_name']
        pwd = req.json['pwd']
        if user_name in self.users:
            return {"user_id": str(self.users.index(user_name)), "result": True}
        return {"result": "Wrong Credentials","success": False}
```

For more information about the `json` tools https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#dealing-with-json. Also in the android side... take a look to https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android most likely you need to use `HttpURLConnection` and specify the HTTP method `client.setRequestMethod(“POST”);`